# How to avoid no internet dialog even having internet wifi connection during phone wake up(unlock) in Android?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-wifi, wakeup

If the user On my app and locked the phone and then unlock it and open the phone with my app on the foreground in the phone already but it shows no internet dialog if the phone is connected to the wifi and in power save mode.

I want to avoid that dialog to show to the user because definitely there is an internet connection in the user phone and that dialog message will misguide the user.
Please help me with how to handle this in the android application. 
Scenario

1.user running application with a wifi internet connection

2.user locked the phone

3.User Unlocked the phone

4.phone open with the application open directly and show no internet dialog but mobile already connected to wifi that is definitely having an internet connection.

5.How to avoid this situation

Comment: show your code it's might help us to find the bug

Comment: Its just an API call in activity onResume() method and I required it to be in onResume()

Comment: show your internet connection check code. since I am also calling api in on Resume and I am not having such kind of issue

Comment: please check with power saving mode on above marshmallow devices